# Python tkinter password checker gui - hashing issue

Tags: python, user-interface, hash, tkinter, md5

I've almost finished my gui. Which is supposed to check an entered password for strength i.e how long it is, upper and lowercase, special characters etc...
Hash that password into an md5 hash, store it in a text file. Then the user would re enter password, re-hashing would take place, then the text file checked to see if that hash was in there. However i cant seem to get the re entered password to hash correctly and use that to check in the file.

My complete code:

```
from tkinter import *
import hashlib
import os
import re

myGui = Tk()
myGui.geometry('500x400+700+250')
myGui.title('Password Generator')
guiFont = font = dict(family='Courier New, monospaced', size=18, color='#7f7f7f')
guiFont2 = font1 = dict(family='Courier New, monospaced', size=18, color='9400d3')


#====== Password Entry ==========
eLabel = Label(myGui, text="Please Enter you Password:   ", font=guiFont)
eLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
ePassword = Entry(myGui, show="*")
ePassword.grid(row=0, column=1)



#====== Strength Check =======


def checkPassword():
    strength = ['Password can not be Blank', 'Very Weak', 'Weak', 'Medium', 'Strong', 'Very Strong']
    score = 1
    password = ePassword.get()

    if len(password) == 0:
        passwordStrength.set(strength[0])
        return

    if len(password) < 4:
        passwordStrength.set(strength[1])
        return

    if len(password) >= 8:
        score += 1

    if re.search("[0-9]", password):
        score += 1

    if re.search("[a-z]", password) and re.search("[A-Z]", password):
        score += 1

    if re.search(".", password):
        score += 1

    passwordStrength.set(strength[score])

passwordStrength = StringVar()
checkStrBtn = Button(myGui, text="Check Strength", command=checkPassword, height=2, width=25, font=guiFont)
checkStrBtn.grid(row=2, column=0)
checkStrLab = Label(myGui, textvariable=passwordStrength, font=guiFont2)
checkStrLab.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

#====== Hash the Password ======


def passwordHash():
    hash_obj1 = hashlib.md5()
    pwmd5 = ePassword.get().encode('utf-8')
    hash_obj1.update(pwmd5)
    md5pw.set(hash_obj1.hexdigest())

md5pw = StringVar()
hashBtn = Button(myGui, text="Generate Hash", command=passwordHash, height=2, width=25, font=guiFont)
hashBtn.grid(row=3, column=0)
hashLbl = Label(myGui, textvariable=md5pw, font=guiFont2)
hashLbl.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)


#====== Log the Hash to a file =======


def hashlog():
    loghash = md5pw.get()

    if os.path.isfile('password_hash_log.txt'):
        obj1 = open('password_hash_log.txt', 'a')
        obj1.write(loghash)
        obj1.write("\n")
        obj1.close()

    else:
        obj2 = open('password_hash_log.txt', 'w')
        obj2.write(loghash)
        obj2.write("\n")
        obj2.close()

btnLog = Button(myGui, text="Log Hash", command=hashlog, height=2, width=25, font=guiFont)
btnLog.grid(row=4, column=0)

#====== Re enter password and check against stored hash ======


def verifyHash():
    hashinput = vHash.get()
    hashobj2 = hashlib.md5(hashinput.encode('utf-8')).hexidigest()

    with open('password_hash_log.txt') as obj3:
        for line in obj3:
            line = line.rstrip()
            if line == hashobj2:
                output.set("Password Match")
            else:
                output.set("Passwords do not match try again")


output = StringVar()
lblVerify = Label(myGui, text="Enter Password to Verify:   ", font=guiFont)
lblVerify.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W)
vHash = Entry(myGui, show="*")
vHash.grid(row=5, column=1)
vBtn = Button(myGui, text="Verify Password", command=verifyHash, height=2, width=25, font=guiFont)
vBtn.grid(row=6, column=0)
vLbl = Label(myGui, textvariable=output, font=guiFont2)
vLbl.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W)

myGui.mainloop()
```

I'm so close to finishing what i need to do so any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you store the first hash in a text file? Just keep it in memory in some variable and compare that to the reentered password.

Comment: Its part of an assignment where the password needs to be verified against a stored hash.

Answer (score 0):

In my previous example nothing was passed through the hexidigest to produce the Hash. I have amended the last part of the code and the gui now works as planned.

The new code:

```
def verifyHash():

    hash_obj2 = hashlib.md5()
    pwmd52 = vHash.get().encode('utf-8')
    hash_obj2.update(pwmd52)
    md5pw2.set(hash_obj2.hexdigest())

    with open('password_hash_log.txt') as obj3:
        for line in obj3:
            line = line.rstrip()
            if line == md5pw2.get():
                output.set("Password Match")
            else:
                output.set("Passwords do not match try again")

md5pw2 = StringVar()
```

Now md5pw2 is the Hashed code and verify Hash takes that and checks each line of a text file to see if that Hash is in there, it then returns Password Match if it finds it.